# powering arduino via solar cells

Tags: arduino, solar-cell

suppose I want to keep an Arduino powered during the night, and recharge it during the day with a solar cell. What kind of circuit do I have to make, how many and which type of batteries, and what size of solar panel do I need to keep it going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**SolArduino v1**](http://www.rachelselectronics.com/categories/open-source-hardware/)

[image: Board]

[image: PCB]

[**Solar Piston v1**](http://www.rachelselectronics.com/2010/09/solar-piston-v1/)

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 3):

I'd start by measuring the power consumption of the Arduino and figure out how to put it to sleep when possible. From what I've [read](http://fightpc.blogspot.com/2008/10/low-power-arduino.html), the Arduino Pro Mini consumes something like 5 mA at 3.3 V, which is around 15 mW. With a solar panel, your capacity factor is likely to be around 10 percent, meaning that it will produce an average power of around 10% of its peak power. This suggests that you need a panel that can produce 150 mW, but I'd probably go for a 1 W panel unless size is an issue.

For batteries, you want to get as low a voltage as you can, while still being above 3.3 V. I might try a 6 V lantern battery.

For wiring, put all three devices (Arduino, battery, and solar panel) in parallel. Example (minus the battery) [here](http://little-scale.blogspot.com/2008/03/connecting-solar-panel-to-arduino.html).

Comment: why parallel? I've seen a slightly more complex diagram for wiring, involving one electrolytic and one diode. Does it make any difference ?

Comment: The diode is a good idea-- it's to prevent the battery from pushing current back through the solar panel when it's dark. I don't think the cap is necessary. If there were no battery, you'd want the cap as a mini-battery to smooth out fluctuations in the panel voltage, but the battery itself will act like a capacitor. (I'm assuming you're using a relatively large battery, not a coin cell.)

Comment: If you run the Arduino at 3.3V (8MHz), you can use a 1W solar panel, 3.7V Li-Poly battery, and Li-Poly charging circuit. A 3.3V DC-DC converter circuit allows you to keep the 3.3V even with 1-3V (1-2 AA batteries).